# collection_select does not display dropdown, does any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Consider these simple, Reminder & event models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reminders
end


class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event
end
```

now, I have build `reminders/new.html.haml` view in following way:

```
%h2 Reminders
= form_for(@reminder, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :event do |event|
    = event.collection_select :id, Event.all, :id, :name
  = f.text_field(:issue_date, class: "datepicker", data: {"date-format" =>"dd/mm/yyyy"}, 'date' => "#{Time.new.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}")
  = f.text_field(:renewal_date, label:"Due Date", class: "datepicker", data: {'date-format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'date' => "#{Time.new.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}"})
  = f.submit
```

This view doesn't throw any errors & reminders minus the `<options>` tag. 
[View http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/f990e124f356330a10839b00cd92f75a.png](http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/f990e124f356330a10839b00cd92f75a.png)

What I want to do is to display `Event.name` in the `<options>`. So what am I missing here?

[Update]
Changed to `form_for` & it generates following html markup

```
<form method="post" id="new_reminder" class="form-horizontal" action="/reminders" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="Yu7Qj4SW+GAMXx9dEL/ohjsqryEkxUXXGy+SHpN97hc=" name="authenticity_token"></div>

                <input type="text" size="30" name="reminder[issue_date]" id="reminder_issue_date" date="20/09/2012" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="datepicker">
                <input type="text" size="30" name="reminder[renewal_date]" label="Due Date" id="reminder_renewal_date" data-date="20/09/2012" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="datepicker">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Reminder" name="commit">
              </form>
```

as you may notice `<option>` tag is missing for some reason.

Comment: This should work.Check the generated html may be some style is get applied on it or check it works or not for a `form_for`

Comment: tested using `form_for` & the markup is attached above. Wonder what am I missing :/

Comment: strange, but i check my own and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, this solution doesn't require  `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. removed it & problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    collection_select(:event, :id, Event.all, :id, :name)

Comment: Tried but the event field is not being displayed. any other ideas?